# App only approved for basic scope

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So my app just got approved, but only with the basic scope. I am creating a MyFollowers app that track new, lost followers etc.. I added video showing my login. Then the amount of following, followers and posts. Then I showed sandbox users for not follow me back.

These are the scopes I need: `basic+follower_list+public_content+relationships`

Any ideas what to do to get more scopes accepted?

Answer (score 0):

From the Instagram page:

> As of 10/1/2017, all permissions other than the basic permission will be  unavailable to submit for or obtain.

If you need these permissions you would have to use the  [new Instagram graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/v2.11) wich works only for instagram business accounts.

Comment: The docs is a bit hard to understand. What permissions do I now need for follow/unfollow users?

Comment: You can't follow/unfollow users anymore. In the old API you would need the relationships scope but instagram is not granting this scope to new apps anymore. In the graph API follow/unfollow users is not supported yet.

Comment: So there is no way to follow or unfollow users? Not even if I make the app just for myself?

Comment: Not with the official API. There are a few unofficial ones on github like [this one](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) that let you follow/unfollow users.

Comment: Will I be able to see the follow status (is following, not following, not followed by) using the basic permission, or do I need to use the new API for that? It doesn't need to perform any actions, just to see the status if I am following the user og not, and if the user is following me or not.

Comment: No you can't do that with basic permission, you would need the follower_list scope.

Comment: I have created a product in developers.facebook.com now, but I can only see submissions instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights and instagram_manage_comments. Where can I get the `follower_list` scope?

Comment: As I wrote before the new graph API does not support follow/unfollow yet.

Comment: Mike, I don't understand how I can use the new API to get a list of who liked my posts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the basic permission ("basic - to read a user’s profile info and media"), which is the only one they are taking requests for now is for photo printing apps and apps like Tinder that retrieve photos.

I have been reading up on this the last few days and can't seem to find much else on the basic permission and how else it may apply, e.g. displaying posts, mind some forums say it doesn't allow this.

However If you look at this link they seem to be getting the thumbs up http://www.iamspecialized.com

Also, Tinder enables users to display 20 (i think) photos directly from Instagram which of course links the viewer to Instagram if they wish, thus they are displaying posts in a way.

See also https://vibbi.com which displays public profiles and posts.

From what sites I've seen with approval, and what I have read, it appears to me that the clause: "to read a user’s profile info and media" is quite broad so that Instagram have discretion as to who they approve. So, if you're not putting forward a great product built on a big budget, then you're likely not to be approved. IMO.

I will be going through the permission process next year. Would love to hear from others who have done so.