# "Invalid scope field(s): public_content" error showing in instagram api in php

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

i am using instagram api using php, I want to follow all users/friends of my friend,So for this
first of all for Authorize,i tried with following code

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxx(clientid)/follows?access_token=xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but i am getting following error

```
code    400
error_type  "OAuthPermissionsException"
error_message   "This request requires scope=follower_list, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=follower_list to be granted this permissions."
```

then i tried with following code

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://mywebsite.com/&response_type=token&scope=follower_list
```

then i am getting following error

```
error_type  "OAuthException"
code    400
error_message   "Invalid scope field(s): follower_list"
```

How can i get that list ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm … you are aware that Facebook is in the process of turning the old Instagram API off, right …? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/

Comment: @misorude: it means for now this is not possible , right ?

Comment: Instagrams old API does not provide access to user information as they are using Instagram Graph API instead now.
Maybe this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47370608/1031705

Answer (score 1):

Instagram documentation:

The OAuth 2.0 specification allows you to specify the scope of the access you are requesting from the user. All approved apps have basic access by default, but if you plan on asking for extended access such as reading public content, liking, commenting, or managing friendships, you will need to specify these scopes in your authorization request. Note that in order to use these extended permissions, you must first submit your app for review. Here are the scopes we currently support:

basic - to read a user’s profile info and media

Comment: I am using only basic access from Instagram, even though I'm getting the same error. Any help?

Comment: Yes, I have also used just basic scope in my xamarin app but still getting same exception @Deilusia